# Beaver and Pollux?

Tags: biology, scientific-names, animals, etymology, mythology

[Castor and Pollux](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_et_Pollux) are famous mythological twins.
[*Castor*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_%28genus%29) is also the genus of beavers.
This makes me wonder two things:

- Are these two *Castor*s related in any way?
- Was this double meaning observed in antiquity?
  (Were beavers known to Romans and did they call them *castor*?)

The two *Castor*s do not look alike and only one of them is famous for riding horses.
Ancient mythology is full of metamorphoses, but I am not aware of a story where Castor becomes a beaver.
Castor and Pollux are also stars in the constellation Gemini, but I have found no trace of beaver-related constellations that could explain identifying beavers with Pollux's brother via naming stars.
I have found no evidence that this double meaning of *Castor* is more than a coincidence.

It seems that the same double meaning for *Castor* also appears in Greek.

Comment: I known this doesn’t really help the issue but apparently some Indian tribes in Canada for quite a long time have been calling the stars of the Gemini constellation the beaver stars.

Comment: @Beaver Welcome to the site! As you point out yourself, that's not an answer but interesting additional information nevertheless. That's why your answer was converted into a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=castor) states

> His [Castor's] name was given to secretions of the animal (Latin castoreum), used medicinally in ancient times. (Through this association his name replaced the native Latin word for "beaver," which was fiber.)

[Castoreum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castoreum) has been used medicinally since Classical times, prominently as an ingredient in [*material medica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materia_medica) and [theria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theriac) — the latter appeared in the [*Amsterdammer Apotheek*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QhdiAAAAcAAJ) as late as 1683, not too long before Linnaeus. Both concoctions had been used by the ancient Greeks and Romans, establishing themselves as supposed cure-alls.

The connection between castoreum and Castor is not as clear. The Online Etymological Dictionary states that Castor was venerated by ancient Greek women as a healer; I have not been able to confirm this in any writings. [This page](http://www.billcasselman.com/cwod_archive/beaver_castor_two.htm) does state that no great explanation has been put forth in this regard, only that there is speculation that Castor (Kastor, if you prefer an alternate spelling) was transformed into a beaver and back in the course of some myth. Again, I have found no evidence of this. The direct mythological aspect here seems to be a dead end.

The second part of your question is more interesting. The ancient Greeks and Romans were well aware of castoreum and used it for a variety of medicinal and health uses. Plutarch, for example, refers to it several times in his *Moralia* ([version in English](https://www.archive.org/stream/plutarchsmoralia00plutuoft/plutarchsmoralia00plutuoft_djvu.txt)). And yes, *castor* was one word used by the Romans to refer to beavers (see [the Lewis Elementary Latin dictionary](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1002193&p2=c)), leading directly to the modern taxonomic usage, including that of Linnaeus in [*Systema Naturae*](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/10277#page/68/mode/1up). Linnaeus's usage, interestingly enough, was originally towards the same species of beaver that the Romans would have been familiar with — the Eurasian beaver, *Castor fiber*.

The naming of the stars [Castor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_(star)) (actually a triple star system) and [Pollux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollux_(star)) seems to be somewhat unrelated to the specifics of the Greek/Roman myths of Castor and Pollux. Rather, the names may have been applied the Alpha Geminorum and Beta Geminorum due to the Babylonian naming of the two stars as "The Great Twins" (see [Rogers (1998)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998JBAA..108....9R)). The idea that the two stars were twins was then passed on to the Greeks, and then the Romans, and thus they used their example of the [divine twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_twins).

The stars are not, however, related to beavers.

Comment: The explanation given in “etymonline” goes back to Kretschmer 1909, but it is rejected by Beekes 2010, who argues that the primary meaning of kastōr is indeed “beaver”, possibly a borrowing from some Asiatic language.